WebClient Invalid Token Response Content type 'application/json' not supported for bodyType=java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>
I am writing a Spring Boot Standalone batch job application which connects to REST API with OAUTH Token protection for Authentication & Authorization.
I configured reactive WebClient but when I execute it against a resource URL I see that the token request get sent and comes back with HTTP Response Code 200.
But after that I get a strange exception that the returned token can not be parsed because the body is to be expected in the format bodyType=java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object> ?
Is JSON not the default mapping configuration for such kind of token requests and responses? what do I miss here ?
Exception:
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ClientAuthorizationException: [invalid_token_response] An error occurred parsing the Access Token response: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported for bodyType=java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>  
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ClientCredentialsReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.lambda$authorize$0(ClientCredentialsReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.java:86)
        Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
        *__checkpoint ? Request to GET http://localhost:8000/api/product [DefaultWebClient]

If not how do I need to configure the WebClient so it understands that the Token Request is in JSON?
POM Extract:
   <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

WebClient Configuration:
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ClientRegistration clientRegistration() {
        return ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("sw6")
                .clientId("xxxxx")
                .clientSecret("xxxxx")
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .tokenUri("http://localhost:8000/api/oauth/token")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean("OAuthWebClient")
    public WebClient webClient(ClientRegistration clientRegistration) {
        InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository registrationRepository = new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistration);
        InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService = new InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(registrationRepository);
        AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager clientManager = new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(registrationRepository, clientService);
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction serverOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientManager);      serverOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("sw6");

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
            .wiretap(HttpClient.class.getCanonicalName(), LogLevel.DEBUG, AdvancedByteBufFormat.TEXTUAL, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        ClientHttpConnector conn = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient); 

        return WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl("http://localhost:8000/api/")
        .clientConnector(conn)
        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .filter(serverOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction)
        .build();
    }
}


And in the "Main"
 @Autowired
    @Qualifier("OAuthWebClient")
    WebClient webClient;

    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
      String responseJson = webClient.get()
        .uri("product")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class)
        .block();
      log.info(responseJson);
    }


Log Statements:
024-07-08 20:36:59.315 [http-nio-3] DEBUG r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [591f7022-1, L:/localhost:65302 - R:/localhost:8000] Handler is being applied: {uri=http://localhost:8000/api/oauth/token, method=POST}
2024-07-08 20:36:59.387 [http-nio-3] DEBUG r.n.http.client.HttpClientOperations     : [591f7022-1, L:/localhost:65302 - R:/localhost:8000] Received response (auto-read:false) : RESPONSE(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1)
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: <filtered>
Content-Type: <filtered>
Transfer-Encoding: <filtered>
Connection: <filtered>
date: <filtered>
pragma: <filtered>
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <filtered>
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: <filtered>
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: <filtered>
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: <filtered>
x-frame-options: <filtered>
X-Content-Type-Options: <filtered>
Referrer-Policy: <filtered>
Content-Security-Policy: <filtered>
Cache-Control: <filtered>
2024-07-08 20:36:59.397 [http-nio-3] DEBUG r.n.http.client.HttpClientOperations     : [591f7022-1, L:/localhost:65302 - R:/localhost:8000] Http client inbound receiver cancelled, closing channel.
2024-07-08 20:36:59.402 [http-nio-3] DEBUG r.n.http.client.HttpClientOperations     : [591f7022-1, L:/192.168.56.105:65302 ! R:/192.168.56.6:8000] Received last HTTP packet
2024-07-08 20:36:59.403 [main      ] INFO  .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-07-08 20:36:59.411 [main      ] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ClientAuthorizationException: [invalid_token_response] An error occurred parsing the Access Token response: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported for bodyType=java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>  
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ClientCredentialsReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.lambda$authorize$0(ClientCredentialsReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.java:86)
        Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
        *__checkpoint ? Request to GET http://localhost:8000/api/product [DefaultWebClient]
Original Stack Trace:
                at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ClientCredentialsReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.lambda$authorize$0(ClientCredentialsReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.java:86)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorMap$27(Mono.java:3840)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorResume$29(Mono.java:3930)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxHide.java:142)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:241)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:315)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxMapFuseable.java:142)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxMapFuseable.java:142)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:180)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:134)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:2236)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:106)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4568)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onError(FluxConcatArray.java:186)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxError.subscribe(FluxError.java:43)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8840)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatArray.java:238)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreElements$IgnoreElementsSubscriber.onComplete(MonoIgnoreElements.java:89)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTakeWhile$TakeWhileSubscriber.onComplete(FluxTakeWhile.java:122)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTakeWhile$TakeWhileSubscriber.onNext(FluxTakeWhile.java:96)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)
                at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:379)
                at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:426)
                at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:815)
                at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:114)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
                at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
                at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
                at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
                at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:333)
                at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:455)
                at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
                at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
                at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1407)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
                at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:918)
                at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
                at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
                at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
                at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
                at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
                at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:994)
                at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
                at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
        Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
                at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:104)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1779)
                at com.mach6.sw6.api.admin.app.AdminClientMain.run(AdminClientMain.java:39)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunner$5(SpringApplication.java:790)
                at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.acceptWithException(ThrowingConsumer.java:83)
                at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:60)
                at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:88)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:798)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:789)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunners$3(SpringApplication.java:774)
                at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
                at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357)
                at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510)
                at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
                at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
                at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
                at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
                at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:774)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:342)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352)
                at com.mach6.sw6.api.admin.app.AdminClientMain.main(AdminClientMain.java:22)
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthorizationException: [invalid_token_response] An error occurred parsing the Access Token response: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported for bodyType=java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.web.reactive.function.OAuth2AccessTokenResponseBodyExtractor.lambda$extract$0(OAuth2AccessTokenResponseBodyExtractor.java:68)
        Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
        *__checkpoint ? Body from POST http://localhost:8000/api/oauth/token [DefaultClientResponse]
Original Stack Trace:
                at org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.web.reactive.function.OAuth2AccessTokenResponseBodyExtractor.lambda$extract$0(OAuth2AccessTokenResponseBodyExtractor.java:68)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorMap$28(Mono.java:3854)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onError(FluxConcatArray.java:186)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxError.subscribe(FluxError.java:43)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8840)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatArray.java:238)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreElements$IgnoreElementsSubscriber.onComplete(MonoIgnoreElements.java:89)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTakeWhile$TakeWhileSubscriber.onComplete(FluxTakeWhile.java:122)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTakeWhile$TakeWhileSubscriber.onNext(FluxTakeWhile.java:96)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)
                at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:379)
                at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:426)
                at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:815)
                at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:114)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
                at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
                at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
                at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
                at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:333)
                at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:455)
                at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
                at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
                at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1407)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
                at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:918)
                at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
                at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
                at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
                at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
                at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
                at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:994)
                at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
                at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)


